# What is an example of a function that is uniformly continuous but not continuous on an interval $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

In the Appendix to Chapter 8 of Spivak's *Calculus*, entitled "Uniform Continuity", there is the following theorem

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on
> $[a,b]$

The absence of the converse seems to imply that it isn't true. What is an example of a function that is uniformly continuous but not continuous on an interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: Uniform continuity is stronger than ordinary continuity. If you don't have continuous, you certainly can't have uniformly continuous!

Comment: Any function being uniformly continuous on an interval means it's continuous on that interval. That's all.

Comment: The reason why the statement is in that form is that it is common belief that only that implication deserves a proof, since uniform continuity implies continuity, unconditionally (and it has probably been mentioned elsewhere in a less LOOK-AT-THIS way). It should be mentioned that exposition of foundational results may also serve the purpose of delivering the most common formulation of said results, which is probably that one for Heine-Cantor.

Comment: You recieved an answer to your question. Is it what you needed? If so, consider accepting the answer. That's how the site works. If it is not what you needed, please explain what is still left unclear.

Answer (score 3):

> The absence of the converse seems to imply that it isn't true.

Not really. The absence of the converse *sometimes* means that it isn't true. Other times, it means that the converse is more broadly true.

In this case, the converse is **more broadly** true. In fact, if $I$ is a bounded interval, and $f: I\to\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous, then $f$ is continuous on $I$. The converse is only true if $I$ is a closed interval.

In other words,

- if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$, then $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$.
- if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.
- if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.
- if $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, then we **cannot say** whether $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$. That is, it **might** be, but we cannot conclude that just because it is continuous on $(a,b)$, that it them must be uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$. For example, $x
  \mapsto \frac1x$ is continuous, but not uniformly continuous, on $(0,1)$.

Comment: No, the converse is always true if $I$ is a closed and bounded interval, but it is certainly not a  necessary condition.

Comment: @AndrewZhang The converse of "if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$" is "if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$", which is **true**. In fact, an even more broad statement, "if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$, then $f$ is continuous on $A$" is true, and this is true no matter what the domain of $f$ is.

Comment: You wrote "The converse is more broadly true. If $I$ is an interval, and $f: I\to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous, then $f$ is continuous on $I$. The converse is only true if $I$ is a closed interval." So it is ambiguous what you are talking about.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Ah, right, I understand now. You just meant I should add "and bounded"? You are right, I reworded my answer. In any case, I hope the four examples at the end will be the most infomative part of the answer :)

Comment: "The converse is only true if $I$ is a closed interval." This seems to suggest that we have the statement "$f\in C(I)$ implies $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I$ only if $I$ is closed." What I meant is that this is a sufficient condition, but it is possible that say $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous. The wording of that part is a bit unclear.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Yes, this is exactly why I added the examples.